# Unable to place the markers between path on the map

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-static-api

I was able to get the static path on the map like this using the code but unable to show the starting and ending points

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=600x600&zoom=12&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:5|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963|40.752946,-73.987384|40.755823,-73.986397
```

Here I was unable to show the markers for the starting point and at the ending point.

How to put the points on starting and ending points

[image: Unable to place the points]

Please help me to find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a markers URL parameter.
Like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&markers=size:mid%7C40.737102,-73.990318|40.755823,-73.986397&size=600x600&zoom=12&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:5|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963|40.752946,-73.987384|40.755823,-73.986397
```

Comment: Did you know how to get the latitude and longitude points to append for exact path from source to destination in android